# $X$ Cauchy distributed then $Y=\frac1X$ also Cauchy distributed

Tags: probability-distributions, density-function, change-of-variable

> If $X$ is Cauchy distributed then $Y:=\frac1X$ is also Cauchy distributed.

It holds:

$$y=g(x)=\frac{1}{x} \Rightarrow g^{-1}(y)=\frac{1}{y} \Rightarrow   (g^{-1}(y))'= -\frac{1}{y^2} $$

How does then follow for density function:

$$f_Y(y)=f_X(g^{-1}(y)) \cdot | (g^{-1}(y))'|$$

Why do I need $|\cdot|$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When transforming random variables, the transformed variable still has to respect the probability axioms, in particular that probability cannot be negative. Hence the absolute value around $(g^{-1}(y))'$ is necessary, otherwise $f_Y(y)$ could assume negative values (and here it would, because $(g^{-1}(y))'=-\frac1{y^2}<0$).

Comment: I do not exactly understand the transformation. How does $(g^{-1}(y))'$ get on the right side?

Comment: @Max This is a special case of the change-of-variables formula for general integrals.

Comment: I see. That is some kind of substitution rule,  because in the end you are interested in F and therefore you need to integrate f

Comment: @Max Something like that, yes. In higher dimensions (more variables) $(g^{-1}(y))'$ becomes the determinant of the Jacobian matrix of the transformation.

Comment: I see:) Thank you very much:)

Comment: Yes  it is possible in 2 min:)